# How to vectorize and speed-up double for-loop for pandas dataframe when doing text similarity scoring

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy

I have the following dataframe:

```
d_test = {
    'name' : ['South Beach', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Ant', 'Big Dog', 'Beach', 'Dear', 'Cat'],
    'cluster_number' : [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2]
}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(d_test)
```

I want to identify similar names in `name` column if those names belong to one cluster number and create unique id for them. For example `South Beach` and `Beach` belong to cluster number `1` and their similarity score is pretty high. So we associate it with unique id, say `1`. Next cluster is number `2` and three entities from `name` column belong to this cluster: `Dog`, `Big Dog` and `Cat`. `Dog` and `Big Dog` have high similarity score and their unique id will be, say `2`. For `Cat` unique id will be, say `3`. And so on.

I created a code for the logic above:

```
# pip install thefuzz
from thefuzz import fuzz

d_test = {
    'name' : ['South Beach', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Ant', 'Big Dog', 'Beach', 'Dear', 'Cat'],
    'cluster_number' : [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2]
}

df_test = pd.DataFrame(d_test)

df_test['id'] = 0

i = 1
for index, row in df_test.iterrows():
    for index_, row_ in df_test.iterrows():
        if row['cluster_number'] == row_['cluster_number'] and row_['id'] == 0:
            if fuzz.ratio(row['name'], row_['name']) > 50:
                df_test.loc[index_,'id'] = int(i)
                is_i_used = True
    if is_i_used == True:
        i += 1
        is_i_used = False
```

Code generates expected result:

```
    name        cluster_number id
0   South Beach 1              1
1   Dog         2              2
2   Bird        3              3
3   Ant         3              4
4   Big Dog     2              2
5   Beach       1              1
6   Dear        4              5
7   Cat         2              6
```

Note, for `Cat` we got `id` as `6` but it is fine because it is unique anyway.

While algorithm above works for test data I am not able to use it for real data that I have (about 1 million rows) and I am trying to understand how to vectorize the code and get rid of two for-loops.

Also `thefuzz` module has `process` function and it allows to process data at once:

```
from thefuzz import process
out = process.extract("Beach", df_test['name'], limit=len(df_test))
```

But I don't see if it can help with speeding up the code.

Comment: how many nunique of df['name']? run `df['name'].nunique()` in your dataset and tell me

Comment: @PandaKim `df['name']` has `419776` unique values

Comment: You have not disclosed `df['cluster_number'].nunique()`,
which seems relevant.
Guessing from your example data, I am going
to imagine that it is "large", or put another way,
that names per cluster is "small".

Comment: @J_H  max(df['cluster_number'].nunique()) is about 200. mean is about 10.

Answer (score 6):

#### tl;dr: Avoid O(N^2) running time if N is big.

> help with speeding up the code.

People get down on `.iterrows()`, calling it "slow".

Switching from `.iterrows` to a vectorized approach
might "speed things up" somewhat, but that's a relative measure.
Let's talk about complexity.

#### time complexity

Your current algorithm is quadratic;
it features a pair of nested `.iterrows` loops.
But then immediately we filter on

> ```
>         if different_cluster and not_yet_assigned:
> ```

Now, that could be workable for "small" N.
But an N of 400K quickly becomes infeasible:

```
>>> 419_776 ** 2 / 1e9
176.211890176
```

One hundred seventy-six billion iterations (with a "B")
is nothing to sneeze your nose at,
even if each filter step has trivial (yet non-zero) cost.

At the risk of reciting facts that have tediously been
repeated many times before,

- sorting costs O(N log N), and
- N log N is very signicantly less than N^2

I'm not convinced that what you want is to "go fast".
Rather, I suspect what you really want is to "do less".
Start by ordering your rows, and then make
a roughly linear pass over *that* dataset.

You didn't specify your typical cluster group size G.
But since there's many distinct cluster numbers,
we definitely know that G << N.
We can bring complexity down from O(N^2) to O(N × G^2).

---

```
df = df_test.sort_values(['cluster_number', 'name'])
```

You wrote

```
for index, row in df_test.iterrows():
    for index_, row_ in df_test.iterrows():
```

Turn that into

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    while ...
```

and use `.iloc()` to examine relevant rows.

The `while` loop gets to terminate as soon
as a new cluster number is seen, instead
of every time having to slog through hundreds of thousands
of rows until end-of-dataframe is seen.

Why can it exit early?
Due to the sort order.

---

A more convenient way to structure this might be
to write a clustering helper.

```
def get_clusters(df):
    cur_num = -1
    cluster = []
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        if row.cluster_number != cur_num and cluster:
            yield cluster
            cluster = []
        cur_num = row.cluster_number
        cluster.append(row)
```

Now your top level code can iterate through a bunch
of clusters, performing a fuzzy match of cost O(G^2)
on each cluster.

The invariant on each generated cluster
is that all rows within cluster
shall have identical cluster_number.

And, due to the sorting,
we guarantee that a given cluster_number
shall be generated at most once.

---

https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Please measure current running time,
implement these suggests,
measure again,
and post code + timings.

Comment: thanks for provided ideas. I posted my answer based on your recommendation. I still wonder if victoried option is possible for this.

Answer (score 4):

**Attempt #1**

Based on @J_H suggestions I made some changes in the original code:

```
d_test = {
    'name' : ['South Beach', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Ant', 'Big Dog', 'Beach', 'Dear', 'Cat', 'Fish', 'Dry Fish'],
    'cluster_number' : [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2]
}

df_test = pd.DataFrame(d_test)

df_test = df_test.sort_values(['cluster_number', 'name'])
df_test.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df_test['id'] = 0

i = 1
for index, row in df_test.iterrows():
    row_ = row
    index_ = index
    
    while index_ < len(df_test) and df_test.loc[index, 'cluster_number'] == df_test.loc[index_, 'cluster_number'] and df_test.loc[index_, 'id'] == 0:
        if row['name'] == df_test.loc[index_, 'name'] or fuzz.ratio(row['name'], df_test.loc[index_, 'name']) > 50:
            df_test.loc[index_,'id'] = i
            is_i_used = True
        index_ += 1
        
    if is_i_used == True:
        i += 1
        is_i_used = False
```

Now instead of hours of computations it runs only `210` seconds for dataframe with `1` million rows where in average each cluster has about `10` rows and max cluster size is about `200` rows.

While it is significant improvement I still looking for vectorized option.

**Attempt #2**

I created vectorized version:

```
from rapidfuzz import process, fuzz
df_test = pd.DataFrame(d_test)
names = df_test["name"]
scores = pd.DataFrame(rapidfuzz.process.cdist(names, names, workers=-1),  columns=names, index=names)
x, y = np.where(scores > 50)
groups = (pd.DataFrame(scores.index[x], scores.index[y])
           .groupby(level=0)
           .agg(frozenset)
           .drop_duplicates()
           .reset_index(drop=True)
           .reset_index()
           .explode("name"))
groups.rename(columns={'index': 'restaurant_id'}, inplace=True)
groups.restaurant_id += 1
df_test = df_test.merge(groups, how="left")
```

but it is not possible to use for dataframe with 1 millions rows because `cdist` returns a matrix of `len(queries) x len(choices) x size(dtype)`. By default this dtype is `float`. So for 1 million names, the result matrix would require `3.6` terrabytes of memory.

Comment: Cool! I think you're looking for one of these two apply's, either https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html or https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html . Though I really do still advise that you adopt the `get_clusters` generator, as that would let you do a (small-ish) number of `.apply` vector operations on sub-problems.

Answer (score 3):

Following on your own answer, you don't need to compute `process.cdist` on all the names, you are interested only on those on the same cluster.

To do so, you can iterate over groups:

```py
threshold = 50
index_start = 0
groups = []

for grp_name, grp_df in df_test.groupby("cluster_number"):
    
    names = grp_df["name"]

    scores = pd.DataFrame(
        data = (process.cdist(names, names, workers=-1)),
        columns = names,
        index = names
    )

    x, y = np.where(scores > threshold)
    grps_in_group = (pd.DataFrame(scores.index[x], scores.index[y])
        .groupby(level=0)
        .agg(frozenset)
        .drop_duplicates()
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .assign(restaurant_id = lambda t: t.index + index_start)
        .explode("name")
    )
    

    index_start = grps_in_group["restaurant_id"].max()+1
    groups.append(grps_in_group)
    
df_test.merge(pd.concat(groups), on="name")

|    | name        |   cluster_number |   id |   restaurant_id |
|---:|:------------|-----------------:|-----:|----------------:|
|  0 | Beach       |                1 |    0 |               0 |
|  1 | South Beach |                1 |    0 |               0 |
|  2 | Big Dog     |                2 |    0 |               1 |
|  3 | Cat         |                2 |    0 |               2 |
|  4 | Dog         |                2 |    0 |               1 |
|  5 | Dry Fish    |                2 |    0 |               3 |
|  6 | Fish        |                2 |    0 |               3 |
|  7 | Ant         |                3 |    0 |               4 |
|  8 | Bird        |                3 |    0 |               5 |
|  9 | Dear        |                4 |    0 |               6 |
```

Yet I am not sure this is an improvement.

Now, transforming the loop functionality in a function we can use `.groupby(...).apply(...)`, however we lose track of the consecutive index. To address that I am using a trick with pandas categorical type:

```py
def create_restaurant_id(
    dframe: pd.DataFrame,
    threshold: int = 50
    ) -> pd.DataFrame:
    
    names = dframe["name"]

    scores = pd.DataFrame(
        data = (process.cdist(names, names, workers=-1)),
        columns = names,
        index = names
    )

    x, y = np.where(scores > threshold)
    
    grps_in_group = (pd.DataFrame(scores.index[x], scores.index[y])
        .groupby(level=0)
        .agg(frozenset)
        .drop_duplicates()
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .assign(restaurant_id = lambda t: t.index)
        .explode("name")
    )
    
    return grps_in_group

(df_test
 .groupby("cluster_number")
 .apply(create_restaurant_id)
 .reset_index(level=0)
 .assign(restaurant_id = lambda t: (
     t["cluster_number"].astype(str) + t["restaurant_id"].astype(str)
     ).astype("category").cat.codes
 )
)
```

In term of performance on my laptop, with such small dataframe, the two are almost identical.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is it possible to have more then one cluster per iteration?

Comment: I am editing and adding to the answer to avoid the for loop. However you may consider other dataframe libraries that are multicore and work in parallel by default.

Comment: Thanks. While both of your answers do not lead to out-of-memory errors, the computation time for one million rows exceeds 30 minutes. It is much slower than a double for loop (it takes only 2 minutes to compute).  It is why I asked about the possibility of adding "batch size" for `"cluster_number"` to your first solution so it would be possible to iterate on more than one cluster per iteration (I think 2000 clusters per iteration would speed up computation and require only ~ 8GB of memory).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are thinking very analytically. Try this :
What I'm doing here is giving a non-repeating ID number (Details below).

```
import pandas as pd

d_test = {
    'name' : ['South Beach', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Ant', 'Big Dog', 'Beach', 'Dear', 'Cat'],
    'cluster_number' : [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2]
}

df_test = pd.DataFrame(d_test)
df_test = df_test.sort_values(['cluster_number', 'name'])
df_test.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# Does the word occur more than once ? (int)
repeat = 0

for i in range(df_test.shape[0]):
    heywtu = df_test[df_test['name'].str.contains(*df_test['name'][i].split())].index.values
    
    # 0 enters the special case, so we took it as 1 directly.
    if i == 0:
            df_test.loc[i,'id'] = i+1
    else : 
        # Does the word occur more than once?
        repeat += len(heywtu) == 2

        # Fill all id column with specific id number
        df_test.loc[i,'id'] = i - repeat


# Editing the id of people with the same name other than 0
    if (len(heywtu) == 2) & (i!=0):
        df_test.loc[i,'id'] = heywtu[0]
        continue
# Special case, If there only 2 values:
if (len(df_test['name'])==2):
    df_test.loc[1,'id'] =2

# For first d_test values
print(df_test.head(10)) 
>>>           name  cluster_number   id
>>> 0        Beach               1  1.0
>>> 1  South Beach               1  1.0
>>> 2      Big Dog               2  2.0
>>> 3          Cat               2  3.0
>>> 4          Dog               2  2.0
>>> 5          Ant               3  4.0
>>> 6         Bird               3  5.0
>>> 7         Dear               4  6.0

# For last d_test values
print(df_test.head(10))
>>>           name  cluster_number   id
>>> 0        Beach               1  1.0
>>> 1  South Beach               1  1.0
>>> 2      Big Dog               2  2.0
>>> 3          Cat               2  3.0
>>> 4          Dog               2  2.0
>>> 5     Dry Fish               2  4.0
>>> 6         Fish               2  4.0
>>> 7          Ant               3  5.0
>>> 8         Bird               3  6.0
>>> 9         Dear               4  7.0

# If there only 2 values
df_test.head()
>>>          name  cluster_number   id
>>> 0      Big Dog               1  1.0
>>> 1  South Beach               2  2.0
```

What is repeat? Well, if other strings contains `Dog` word its gonna be counted, like `Dog` and `Big Dog` , and substrack numbers with index number. I hope its gonna helpful for your problem.

Comment: thank you for the answer but output does not seems right. `id` for `Big Dog` and `Dog` should be the same

Comment: Edited! Does it helpful?

Comment: Thanks for edit but please consider the following input `d_test = {'name' : ['South Beach', 'Big Dog'], 'cluster_number' : [2,  1]} `. Your solution gives the same id `1` for both names. But they should be different because they belong to different clusters.

Comment: I thought this code is for Big data but I added new case for value 2